# Python3 raise exception on multiple failures, with traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

In python 3, exceptions can be chained, like this:

```
try:
  7/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
  raise ValueError("Invalid division")

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
#
# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
# ValueError: Invalid division
```

What if I have the following situation:

- A class with a method that may either succeed or throw an error.
- I have a bunch of instances of that class in a list.
- Somewhere I call that method for every instance on the list.
- It is enough for one of them to succeed. If every instance fails I throw an error.

Now, if I have to throw an error, I want to print all exceptions thrown during the test of each instance in the list. Code to clarify:

```
instances_to_test = [instance0, instance1, instance2]
failures = [] # List of all the thrown exceptions
success = False # True if one of the instances in the list succeeds
for instance in instances_to_test:
  try:
    instance.method_may_raise() # May raise an Error
    success = True
    break
  except Exception as e:
    failures.append(e)
if not success:
  # ... What to do here ...
```

An ideal solution to the line in the comment would look something like:

```
if not success:
  raise MultipleFailException("Could not find an adequate instance", parents=failures)

# 0 ------------------------------------
#
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
# ValueError: Message of instance0
#
# 1 ------------------------------------
#
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
# ValueError: Message of instance1
#
# 2 ------------------------------------
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
# ValueError: Message of instance2
#
# During handling of the above exception(s), another exception occurred:
#
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
# MultipleFailException: Could not find an adequate instance
```

Can this be done in a 'clean' way or should I fiddle with the stack trace like in the python 2 days?

Comment: A somewhat banal solution would be to simply append booleans to an array based on if they pass or not(catching all the failures) and then check `any()` after the entire list is complete, throwing the relevant error.

Comment: Yes,  that could be done. I want to preserve the failure information to further debugging though. That's why in the example I'm collecting all the exceptions. But I suspect I'll need stack information too in order to have the result I desire.